# DefaultCellRenderer() stops working when column width = 0

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable

So, the thing is that I have a JTable which turns rows orange when the data on one of the columns is 'true' (using a class which extends DefaultCellRenderer), problem is I don't want to show that column, so I've tried removing it or setting its width to 0, but when I do that, it no longer highlights the row in orange. Is there a way to do this or does it always have to be shown info?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've tried removing it or setting its width to 0, but when I do that, it no longer highlights the row in orange

I guess because the width is 0, there is nothing to render so the renderer is never invoked.

In any case, don't use a cell width of 0. As you tab through the table that column will still get focus, but the user won't know it has focus which will confuse the user.

Instead if you want to hide a column then remove the `TableColumn` from the `TableColumnModel`. You get the `TableColumnModel` from the JTable by using the `getColumnModel()` method. Removing the column from the model just prevents the column from being displayed but the data is still contained in the `TableModel`.

> I have a JTable which turns rows orange when the data on one of the columns is 'true'

You can override the `prepareRenderer(...)` method of the JTable to do this easily. This will work even you have columns with different types of data so there is no need to create multiple renderers.

The basic logic is:

```
JTable table = new JTable(...)
{
    public Component prepareRenderer(
        TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column)
    {
        Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);

        if (!isRowSelected(row))
        {
            c.setBackground(getBackground());
            int modelRow = convertRowIndexToModel(row);
            boolean highlight = (Boolean)getModel().getValueAt(modelRow, ???);
            if (highlight) c.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
        }

        return c;
    }
};
```

Check out [Table Row Rendering](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/) for more information and a working example. The example on the "Data" tab does what you want.

Comment: Thanks,I bet this works fine, but sadly, I can't figure out where to put this code to make it work or how, thanks anyway.

Comment: I will, however, take note of your advice about removing columns and not just hiding them!

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this. I assume that you are familiar with table cell renderer. you can override the getTableCellRendererComponent method and change the color like below:

```
 public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
      boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

      // Get default renderer from the table

    TableCellRenderer renderer = table.getDefaultRenderer(table.getColumnClass(column));
    Component comp = renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value,
        isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

    if (value.equals("true") && row == 1 && col== 1){
       comp.setBackground("YOUR COLOR");
    }
}
```

Comment: (1-) Don't use "==" for object comparison. Instead use the `equals(...)` method. How does this render the "row" orange when you only do this for a specific column? Why is it only being done for the row with index 1?